# ORA-06550 & 00904 on delete statement inside pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Once I run the following block:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable;
  dbms_output.put_line('INFO: Calling stack');
  
  delete from A
  where B_ID in (
    select ID
    from B
    where B_COL is null
  );
END;
/
```

I always get the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
>
> PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "B_COL": invalid identifier

Am I not allowed to place delete statements inside pl/sql blocks? The column "B_COL" definitely exists.

Any idea what this could be or should I look elsewhere? I'm stuck on it. Any kind of input would be more than appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to run the delete statement properly outside the pl/sql block. Can you describe table `B` for us showing that `B_COL` column exists?

Comment: It's a play from a real table schema which I can't show, sorry, so no describing, but it does exist. The statement does run properly outside the PL/SQL block.

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. Most questions on SO get asked precisely because the OP's assumptions are incorrect in one way or another. If you can't show the real table, then post a complete but minimal script with dummy tables that we can use to reproduce the error.  Have a look at William Robertson's answer for what a complete and minimal script looks like. Can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.

```
create table a (b_id integer);
create table b (id integer, b_col integer);

begin
  delete from a
  where b_id in (
    select id
    from b
    where b_col is null
  );
end;
/
```

There must be something else wrong in your actual code.

Comment: yep, the cleanup was added to a constraint before the incremental installation is applied in which the column - in this case "B_COL" is added. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The block should run. The message will only arrive incase the columns mentioned here does not exist or exists with some different name. Please check the table description once again.